# how do I use htaccess to redirect on test wamp server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, wamp, wampserver

I have a site on both a live server and locally on a wampserver. The wampserver address is 
`//localhost/testsite/` .
(the live site is just the domain name).

So that I dont have to hardcode "/testsite/" into my test urls, how can I use my local .htaccess file to use the /testsite/ area? (testsite is the apache alias)

My files are all in the root folder and called page1.php, page2.php, index.php etc. however when I link to page2 it fails because its calling the the relative path to the server ie. just `//localhost/page2.php` not the expected `//localhost/testsite/page2.php`

I've tried several htaccess rules but they just try and make apache look in a /testsite/ subfolder for page2.php instead of root.

Should I be using htaccess for this? If so what should the rules be. If not what is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have this code in localhost .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/testsite/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /testsite/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however that creates a double entry result ie //localhost/testsite/testsite/index.php can you explain?

Comment: Ok, now the duplicate is gone but get this error - "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: Doh! ok, the initial load now works with //localhost/testsite/index.php but as soon as I click the link to page2 the url changes to //localhost/page2.php and fails to load the page.

Comment: That shouldn't happen since above rule will be applicable to all the URLs. Make sure above is in DOCUMENT_ROOT

Comment: Yep the .htaccess is in the c:/wampserver/www/testsite/ folder along with index.php and all pages etc.

Comment: That's the problem. `.htaccess` should be in `c:/wampserver/www/`

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this. As soon as I moved `.htaccess` into `c:/wampserver/www/`, my website worked! Thanks a ton!!!